# jQuery:Selecting only the hovered instance of an element?

Tags: jquery

New to jQuery and well everything. Sorry if this is obvious.

Here's my fiddle (ignore my horrible layout skills): http://jsfiddle.net/bBd8H/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="effect"></div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="imginfo"></div>
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="imginfo"></div>
```

The outer div might repeat many times (blog posts).

jQuery:

```
$(function ($) {
    $('#effect').hide();
    $('.imginfo').hide();

    $('.inner .image').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#effect').show();
        $('.outer .imginfo').show();
    });
    $('.inner .image').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#effect').hide();
        $('.outer .imginfo').hide();
    });
});
```

What happens is all the .imginfo divs in existence show up, not just the one inside the .outer div the image which is being hovered over is in.

How can I get it to just display only the relevant imginfo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a combination of `this` which will represent the object that triggered the event and and `.closest()` and `.find()` to find the `.imgeinfo` in your branch of the tree.

```
$(function ($) {
    $('#effect').hide();
    $('.imginfo').hide();

    $('.inner .image').mouseenter(function () {
        $('#effect').show();
        $(this).closest(".outer").find("imginfo").show();
    });
    $('.inner .image').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#effect').hide();
        $('.outer .imginfo').hide();
    });
});
```

By way of explanation of this line:

```
$(this).closest(".outer").find("imginfo").show();
```

Break it down piece by piece:

`$(this)` makes a jQuery object out of the object that triggered the event (the object the the mouse entered)

`$(this).closest(".outer")` goes up to the parent of your branch.

`$(this).closest(".outer").find("imginfo")` then finds the imginfo in your branch.

Comment: Thank you and thanks for the explanation. I'd tried .closest and all the similar ones but I hadn't thought of combining them to go up/down the tree.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the context (`this`) to search for the revelant `.imginfo`:

```
$('.inner .image').mouseenter(function () {
    $('#effect').show();
    $(this).closest(".outer").find(".imginfo").show();
});
```

The `mouseleave` is analogous.

**Edit**: Use `closest` instead of `parents`, to avoid wrong behavior in case of nesting.